# Switch disks to another identical HP ML360 G6 with P410i array controller

Tags: hp, hard-drive

In case of hardware failure, for example motherboard/processor, is it possible to put the disks of a raid 1 into a spare server to be back online asap.

If a disk failes and i want to use a disk of the spare server, which is also used as a test server, what do i have to do on the test server to get the disk clean for automatic rebuilding.

The hardware is identical, i bought them at the same time with the same specs.

The spare server is used for testing and spare parts.

Thanks in advance for the answer(s).

Answer (score 2):

Yep, this functionality is not only possible but very specifically designed to support just that feature. You can just move a whole controller and/or the disks it manages from one machine to another and it'll 'just work' (may need a couple of reboots to fully take everything into consideration though).

As for disks if you replace one disk that's already in an array with another single disk that was in another array or blank then by default it'll just steadily add that new disk into the array in the background.

Hope this answers your questions.

Comment: +1 for having done this on HP DL380 with p410 raid controllers.  If the OS is windows, you have to import the foreign disks (if not the OS boot vol), but it worked like a champ.